# Facebook Connect Dialog Popup

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

When using the "Connect" facebook connect button, when I click it, it opens up a new popup window outside of the current window. This is quite annoying, how am I able to use the inline modal dialog that is found on most sites?

I've attached a sample site to see if you can make anything out of it.

http://www.giglocator.com/connect/index.php

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook removed the inline login dialog box for security reasons. However, if a user is logged in to Facebook, but has not yet authorized your app, the pop-up asking them to authorize your app will be inline. Anything that asks for a Facebook password, however, will be displayed in a pop-up so that the user can see the URL of the site that is getting their password. It gives the user some peace of mind.

I tried to figure out why mine changed on me, but it didn't. The inline box gets displayed for logged in users that have never used your site/app before. An FB user that is NOT logged in to Facebook will get the pop-up.

Answer (score 3):

"Previously, the Connect with Facebook dialog appeared in an IFrame "lightbox" within the browser window. After tomorrow's weekly code push, the dialog will pop up in a separate browser window, with an address bar, which matches the user login flow when the user is not logged in to Facebook and tries to connect accounts with your site."

http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=312